# paste network directory and file protocols as hyperlinks

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, wysiwyg, add-on, ckeditor4.x

I'm using ckeditor4 on an internal enterprise application and users interact with a web based ui. Users are asked to link to internal network directories. We have enabled link access from this specific implementation to our network. I have not found a plugin or a guide to add a configuration that recognizes the "file://" protocol or a network location is pasted into the editor window. CKEditor5's "Link" solves this quite nicely, however the licensing to distribute prevents me from using it.

The user base is very business focused and would like the editor to simply recognize these other protocols after the user clicks enter or space like a familiar tool such as MS Word. Asking some of my users to click Control + K and selecting a link protocol is probably a stretch.

Most of the other posts I've come across are asks to limit this behavior.

Does anyone have experience solving this?

I've downloaded, tinkered with, and explored all of the available plugins and add ons. I've provides paste form word plugin and all other domain/url/route based plugins.